# Sort array by alphabet using Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am making an launcher for my phone and I need to sort the apps by alphabet.

```
 Appslist = ArrayList<AppInfo>()

    val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null)
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)
    val allApps = this.packageManager.queryIntentActivities(i, 0)

    for (ri in allApps) {
        val app = AppInfo()
        app.label = ri.loadLabel(this.packageManager)
        app.packageName = ri.activityInfo.packageName
        app.icon = ri.activityInfo.loadIcon(this.packageManager)
        if(app.label?.toString()!!.length >= searchWord.length && app.label?.toString()!!.substring(0, searchWord.length) == searchWord.toUpperCase() && searchWord != "" ||
            app.label?.toString()!!.length >= searchWord.length && app.label?.toString()!!.substring(0, searchWord.length) == searchWord.toLowerCase() && searchWord != "" ||
            app.label?.toString()!!.length >= searchWord.length && app.label?.toString()!!.substring(0, searchWord.length) == searchWord.capitalize() && searchWord != "" ||
            app.label?.toString()!!.length >= searchWord.length && app.label?.toString()!!.substring(0, searchWord.length) == searchWord && searchWord != ""){

            if(app.packageName != "com.david.launcher" ){
                Appslist.add(app)
            }

        }
        if(searchWord == ""){
            if(app.packageName != "com.david.launcher"){
                Appslist.add(app)
            }
        }

    }
```

Here is my list type (I don't really know if it's called list type, but I hope you'll understand):

```
public class AppInfo {
internal var label: CharSequence? = null
internal var packageName: CharSequence? = null
internal var icon: Drawable? = null
internal var isInFav: Boolean? = false
```

Comment: use Collections.sort(your_list)
this will give you sorted list

Comment: @pratikvekariya your comment is incorrect, it is list of classes that do not implement `Comparable` and therefore has no natural order, your method fails, and in addition it is not idiomatic for Kotlin.

Comment: David, is your question answered or are you looking for something else?

Comment: yes, it is. ( :

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The idiomatic way is to use the [`sortedBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-by.html) extension method for `List` if you want to sort into a copy of the list.  Or use [`sortBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sort-by.html) extension on a `MutableList` if you want to sort in-place without a copy.  An `ArrayList` would work as either list type.

```kotlin
// Sort a readonly list into a copy of the list

val appsList: List<AppInfo> = ...

val sortedAppsList = appsList.sortedBy { it.label?.toString() }
```

versus:

```kotlin
// Sort a mutable list in-place

val appsList: MutableList<AppInfo> = ...

appList.sortBy { it.label?.toString() }
```

and if holding as an `ArrayList` it is the same, but not idiomatic to have a reference directly to this concrete type.

```kotlin
// Sort an ArrayList list into a copy of the list

val appsList: ArrayList<AppInfo> = ...  // ALERT! not idiomatic

val sortedAppsList = appsList.sortedBy { it.label?.toString() }

// or if you want, feel free to sort in-place

appsList.sortBy { it.label?.toString() }
```

Note the `toString()` on the `label: CharSequence` member.  You have to be careful sorting on a reference of type `CharSequence` as it is undefined what is its behavior for sorting (see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html)

> This interface does not refine the general contracts of the equals and hashCode methods. The result of comparing two objects that implement CharSequence is therefore, in general, undefined.

If the `CharSequence` is already a `String` (likely is), then there is no harm in calling `toString()` as it just returns itself.

Also keep in mind that the nullable `CharSequence` has to be handled as well, and you need to decide where you want nulls: at the start or end of the list.  I think the default is for them to go to the start.

---

*Other notes about your code in the question:*

Use the `List` or `MutableList` interface instead of the concrete class to reference the type, and use the methods from Kotlin stdlib to do actions upon the list.  Also use `val` instead of `var` for references that will not change (*meaning it will always point to the same list regardless of whether the list contents could change*).

The big `if` statement you have can be reduced a lot, go from...

```kotlin
if(app.label?.toString()!!.length >= searchWord.length && app.label?.toString()!!.substring(0, searchWord.length) == searchWord.toUpperCase() && searchWord != "" ||
    app.label?.toString()!!.length >= searchWord.length && app.label?.toString()!!.substring(0, searchWord.length) == searchWord.toLowerCase() && searchWord != "" ||
    app.label?.toString()!!.length >= searchWord.length && app.label?.toString()!!.substring(0, searchWord.length) == searchWord.capitalize() && searchWord != "" ||
    app.label?.toString()!!.length >= searchWord.length && app.label?.toString()!!.substring(0, searchWord.length) == searchWord && searchWord != ""){

    if(app.packageName != "com.david.launcher" ){
        Appslist.add(app)
    }

}
if(searchWord == ""){
    if(app.packageName != "com.david.launcher"){
        Appslist.add(app)
    }
}
```

to simpler:

```kotlin
if (app.packageName != "com.david.launcher" &&
        (searchWord.isBlank() || 
         app.label?.startsWith(searchWord, ignoreCase = true) == true)) {
    appsList.add(app)
}
```

You should [browse the standard library](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/index.html) to get an idea of what is available so that you broaden your toolkit for the future.

Answer (score 1):

```
class CustomClass {
    var id: String = ""
    var name: String = ""
}

fun sortAlphabetically(arrayList: ArrayList< CustomClass >): ArrayList< CustomClass >{
        var returnList: ArrayList< CustomClass > = arrayListOf()
        var list = arrayList as MutableList< CustomClass >
        list.sortWith(Comparator { o1: CustomClass, o2: CustomClass ->
            o1.name.compareTo(o2.name)
        })
        returnList = list as ArrayList< CustomClass >
        return returnList
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `Collections.sort()` and either a custom implementation of `Comparator<AppInfo>` that operates on AppInfo.label, or making AppInfo class implement `Comparable` interface and implement the `compareTo` method in a way that just compares the label fields.

Comment: This answer is incomplete because it is a more complex issue.  First, the datatypes available for sorting are not sortable (`CharSequence`), and it is not idiomatic Kotlin type create a `Comparator` just for a one-off sort, nor to add `Comparable` to class again for a one-off sort.  Also null handling has to be taken into account given all the types are nullable in the class.